# Way to Make a Better Looking Dendrogram than in Seurat?

Tags: r, seurat

I'm trying to make a hierarchical clustering tree from the clustering produced by Seurat's clustering function. Their functions, BuildClusterTree and PlotClusterTree, produce a frankly ugly tree based on SNN (shared nearest neighbor) algorithm that you can't manipulate with ggplot2. I'm trying to figure out how to use other functions to plot the clustering already produced by Seurat, but I can't figure out how or what R package would work best. Does anyone have any advice for me?

Comment: The `dendextend` package has lots of useful functionality, it may be of some use to you.

Comment: It's a good package, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to know how to extract the clustering data from the Seurat object and then make that into a dendrogram. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [clustree](https://lazappi.github.io/clustree/articles/clustree.html#plotting-a-tree-1) package for this purpose